# autostsm stsm_estimate Error: exo must be a data frame or data table

Tags: r

Using package `autostsm`, function `stsm_estimate` with the MWE code below generates the error `Error in stsm_estimate(y, exo = x) :  exo must be a data frame or data table`

```
x <- data.frame(cbind(runif(10),runif(10)))
y <- runif(10)
library(autostsm)
fitstsm <- stsm_estimate(y, exo=x)
```

How to fix it and make the estimation run?

Edit: I also tried

```
library(autostsm)
x <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + sample(10), c = cbind(runif(10),runif(10)))
y <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + sample(10), c = runif(10))
fitstsm <- stsm_estimate(y, exo=x)
```

which generates the same error.

RStudio
Version 1.3.1093
"Apricot Nasturtium" (aee44535, 2020-09-17) for Ubuntu Bionic
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Answer (score 0):

Documentation of `?stsm_estimate` suggests that `y` should be a time series dataset or 2 column dataframe with date column.

This works :

```
library(autostsm)
y <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + sample(10), c = runif(10))
fitstsm <- stsm_estimate(y)
```

Comment: However, with exogenous variables (which I want to use), it still does not: `library(autostsm)
x <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + sample(10), c = cbind(runif(10),runif(10)))
y <- data.frame(Date = Sys.Date() + sample(10), c = runif(10))
fitstsm <- stsm_estimate(y, exo=x)` generates the same error I had above.

Comment: I think there is a bug in the function. It has got a check as ` if(!is.data.frame(exo) | !is.data.table(exo))`. However, it should be `if(!(is.data.frame(x) | is.data.table(x)))`. Checked the source code from here https://rdrr.io/cran/autostsm/src/R/stsm_estimate.R

Comment: Then it's easier to use a different package for VARX. I tried `dse`, but it does not seem to output standard errors or statistical significance for individual coefficients. Will try `MTS` next.

Answer (score 0):

I will work on making this fix in the next update of autostsm. Thanks for posting!